# Failed s3fs mount due to Timezone skew

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs

```
Apr 22 05:54:59 ubuntuserver s3fs[10143]: s3fs.cpp:set_s3fs_log_level(297): change debug level from [CRT] to [INF]
Apr 22 05:54:59 ubuntuserver s3fs[10143]:     PROC(uid=0, gid=0) - MountPoint(uid=0, gid=0, mode=40755)
Apr 22 05:54:59 ubuntuserver s3fs[10145]: init v1.85(commit:381835e) with OpenSSL
Apr 22 05:54:59 ubuntuserver s3fs[10145]: check services.
Apr 22 05:54:59 ubuntuserver s3fs[10145]:       check a bucket.
Apr 22 05:54:59 ubuntuserver s3fs[10145]: curl.cpp:ResetHandle(1879): The S3FS_CURLOPT_KEEP_SENDING_ON_ERROR option could not be set. For maximize performance you need to enable this option and you should use libcurl 7.51.0 or later.
Apr 22 05:54:59 ubuntuserver s3fs[10145]:       URL is https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketubuntuserver/
Apr 22 05:54:59 ubuntuserver s3fs[10145]:       URL changed is https://bucketubuntuserver.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
Apr 22 05:55:01 ubuntuserver s3fs[10145]: curl.cpp:RequestPerform(2273): HTTP response code 403, returning EPERM. Body Text: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>#012<Error><Code>RequestTimeTooSkewed</Code><Message>The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.</Message>
<RequestTime>Mon, 22 Apr 2019 05:54:59 GMT</RequestTime>
<ServerTime>2019-04-22T06:23:01Z</ServerTime>
<MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds>900000</MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds>
<RequestId>2CDB15BFC9072D0D</RequestId><HostId>grA/XIvT7zLUh9jLUxYGAs8jOtMs762CPMX+TM6GdAVvAB36/b8hH0dVOugVBWRpHX3O63V2Bv8=</HostId></Error>
Apr 22 05:55:01 ubuntuserver s3fs[10145]: curl.cpp:CheckBucket(3305): Check bucket failed, S3 response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>#012<Error><Code>RequestTimeTooSkewed</Code><Message>The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.</Message>
<RequestTime>Mon, 22 Apr 2019 05:54:59 GMT</RequestTime>
<ServerTime>2019-04-22T06:23:01Z</ServerTime>
<MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds>900000</MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds><RequestId>2CDB15BFC9072D0D</RequestId><HostId>grA/XIvT7zLUh9jLUxYGAs8jOtMs762CPMX+TM6GdAVvAB36/b8hH0dVOugVBWRpHX3O63V2Bv8=</HostId></Error>
Apr 22 05:55:01 ubuntuserver s3fs[10145]: s3fs.cpp:s3fs_check_service(3868): invalid credentials(host=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com) - result of checking service.
Apr 22 05:55:01 ubuntuserver s3fs[10145]: Pool full: destroy the oldest handler
Apr 22 05:55:01 ubuntuserver s3fs[10145]: s3fs.cpp:s3fs_exit_fuseloop(3444): Exiting FUSE event loop due to errors
Apr 22 05:55:01 ubuntuserver s3fs[10145]: destroy
```

i had my credentials correct,but i wasnt able to mount s3 due to the clock difference. My server is using UTC which was late by  26 minutes. My problem is solved by fixing ntp sync but:-
1) I want to confirm if the s3fs or any aws tool i use also send the Clock information to S3 ? as  is present but its GMT instead of UTC. The s3 seems to be using UTC when comparing it to servers properly synced to ntp. 
2) Can we use any timezone provided that is properly synced with good NTP server ?

Answer (score 2):

S3 signs requests including the client's current time to prevent attackers from replaying requests at a later time.  Thus if your client has the incorrect time, the server will treat it as an invalid request.  Both the client and server use UTC/GMT; the time zone does not matter.  Configuring ntp as you did should resolve these issues.